# Where is the geth.exe in the Ethereum mist?

Tags: ethereum

I'm running Ethereum Mist on Windows 7. Mist Version is 0.8.6.

I can't find the geth.exe in the Mist github.

https://github.com/ethereum/mist

In the version 0.8.2, the geth path was "`mist\nodes\geth\win32-x64\geth.exe`".

Anyone help me.

Comment: @Mikkel, why is it ruby?

Comment: My apologies, I thought I saw a reference to gems. I had never heard of it, so assumed it was a wrong tag

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you will find `geth.exe` in a path like `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\Mist\binaries\Geth\unpacked`.

The answer on the [Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/where-is-the-geth-exe-in-the-ethereum-mist) has more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest geth.exe from here -

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases